# 24 hours time picker for vueJS

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

In my vuejs application I'm using input field to enter a time.

field type is time

```
<!-- Start Time -->
                    <div v-if="this.selectedValue=== '1'" class="container mx-auto flex bg-white px-6 py-1 space-x-2">
                            <dashboard-input-label class="col-sm-2 mb-2 w-full" identifier="shift_start_time">
                                Start time
                            </dashboard-input-label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10 mb-6 w-full">   
                                    <input 
                                        name="shift_start_time" 
                                        type="time"
                                        class="form-input w-full relative z-10"
                                        placeholder="Start time"
                                    >
                            </div>   
                    </div>
                    <!-- Start Time -->
```

This'll give me an output as follows,

[image]

But I need this time picker to be a 24 hours one without having AM and PM

[image]

How can achieve this, since [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time) also does not have proper explanation on this....

Answer (score 2):

It says in the MDN page you linked to in your question that all browsers choose whether the time picker is 12-hr or 24-hr based on the system locale.

Example from the Chrome portion:

> ... with slots to enter hours and minutes in 12 or 24-hour format ***depending on operating system locale*** ...

From the Firefox portion:

> It also uses a 12- or 24-hour format for inputting times, ***based on system locale.***

If you want all users to see a 24-hour picker, you will need to use a JavaScript picker instead of the browser built-in picker.

Comment: hm, thank you so much for the great insight, any suggested JS picker to use with vue?

Comment: @ArcticFox I use [this one](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/time-pickers/), but you need to be using the whole Vuetify framework in order to use it. I've seen [this one](https://github.com/phoenixwong/vue2-timepicker) and [this one](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-timepicker) which both can do what you want, but I haven't used them myself.

Answer (score 1):

The appearance you refer to is browser defined. If you want to customize it, you can do it with CSS. My advice would be to add a time picker component written in Vue, so it takes away the issue of creating a custom time picker.